# How to activate mysqldb for Django in virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv, mysql-python

OK. So I've been treading on the thin edge of madness trying to get a Python virtualenv with Django set up. Tried a couple of different tutorials, first on Mac and then on Linux (Ubuntu), and always get as far as installing the Django package, and then I try and set up the database and everything just melts down. At first I was getting a lot of "mysql_config not found" and architecture compatibility errors (which was when I moved over to trying it on Linux)...now I think I've finally gotten it installed and not conflicting with anything and I don't know what to do next. I'm supposed to edit Django's settings file with the database info (name, UN, PW, and port), and I don't know where to look for this information.

So...my questions:

1. Is MySQL automatically running on Ubuntu if it is installed? If not, how do I turn it on?
2. Where do I edit databases? I'm a PHP person in general and this is early days with my forays into Python...I've generally done most of my database management through PHPMyAdmin...I know there's a command line for MySQL and I'd be able to use it but I don't know how to turn it on.
3. How do I find out what port MySQL is running on?

Again, this is an install in a virtualenv, if that makes any difference to the answers. I apologize if this is a totally noobish question but all the Django setup tutorials I've found seem to just assume I know this step.

Thanks much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- mysql not installed on ubuntu by default, if you need to start mysql on the boot try:

```
chkconfig mysql on
```

2- mysql has a advanced commandline. just try in terminal:

```
mysql
use DB;
SELECT * FROM tbl1;
```

3- mysql runing on port 3306. and you can find port by this:

```
netstat -tnlp | grep mysql
```

finally you must be look at: [Using PIP in a virtual environment, how do I install MySQL-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960305/using-pip-in-a-virtual-environment-how-do-i-install-mysql-python)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue! (chkconfig seemed a little confused by everything but really the port and the fact that I needed to install more than the python mysqldb package was what I needed to know. :)